# How do I use setTimeout or setInterval while iterating over an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration, settimeout, setinterval

I need to continuously iterate over an array (which actually contains ids used to generate canvax images).

So I need to iterate over the array of keys over and over again, with ids being set with a delay.

```
function animateCanvas() {
    keys = getKeys();
    let offset = 0;
    keys.forEach(function(key){
        setTimeout(function(){
            animateFrame(key);
        }, 2000 + offset);
        offset += 2000;
        keys = [];
    });
}


function animateFrame(id) {
    const animationCanvas = document.querySelector(`.canvas-animation`);
    const animationContext = animationCanvas.getContext('2d');
    const canvas1 = document.getElementById(id);
    animationContext.clearRect(0, 0, animationCanvas.width, animationCanvas.height);
    animationContext.drawImage(canvas1, 0,0, 170, 170, 0, 0 , 150, 150);
}
```

Expected result would be endless setting another image to canvas via animateFrame(key) with a delay of 2 seconds

Comment: I'd use a plain for loop and reset the iterator when *length* is reached. *forEach* sets the elements to visit at the start and will not revisit elements.

Answer (score 0):

This approach won't work as you want to continuously iterate over images. I would suggest user setInterval for it.

try the below piece of code

```
// This is your array of images
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// This is your canvas displaying function
function something(x) {console.log(x)}

setInterval(() => {
  // It checks if we have reached the end
  if(curr == x.length - 1)
    curr = 0;

  something(x[curr]);
  curr++;
}, 2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [`.requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) rather than a loop? It is actually quite ideal for your use case.

This is what it would look like. Note the comment about where to add the image to the canvas.

```js
const data = ["<div></div>", "<section></section>", "<article></article>"];
// Set delay to 5000 for 5 seconds
const delay = 2000;
// set previousCall to 1 to wait for first or -(delay) to start immediately 
let previousCall = -(delay);

function animateCanvas(now) {
  if (now - previousCall >= delay) {
    // grab data from array in some fashion
    let id = parseInt(now/3 % 3);
    animateFrame(id);
    previousCall = now;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(animateCanvas);
}
requestAnimationFrame(animateCanvas);

function animateFrame(id) {
    document.body.innerHTML += data[id];
}
```

```css
div, section, article {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 3px;
}
div {
  background-color: blue;

}
section {
  background-color: yellow;

}
article {
  background-color: orange;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```